# For using SQL in C which header files we need to include in the program?

Tags: c, database, oracle, oracle-call-interface

In my C program I have to make a connection to a database where I am using these statements:

```
EXEC SQL INCLUDE sqlca;
EXEC SQL begin declare section;
EXEC SQL end declare section;
```

But I am getting error for `EXEC`. It says

```
`EXEC' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Am I missing any header file or something else which enables to use these commands?

Comment: Dude - what database are you intefacing to, and what compiler are you using???  Here is a link to one (of many!) example of "embedded SQL".

Comment: I am interfacing to oracle database and I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: Also `EXEC SQL INCLUDE sqlca;` is not valid C code, that's why you get  the `'EXEC' undeclared` error from GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Good: thank you for the clarification.

In the case of Oracle, you're going to need a copy of Pro*C.  This integrates with your gcc compiler.

Here's a good tutorial for using Pro*C:

- http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/pro-c-tutorial

And of course there's plenty of information on OTN.